# Anyway to get Hazelcast List size?

Tags: hazelcast

https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/clients/rest.html
Here we have reference to get Queue/map size using rest api but couldn't find way to fetch list size.

```
curl -v -X GET \http://<member IP address>:<port>/hazelcast/rest/queues/myEvents/size
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [related code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/ascii/rest/HttpCommandProcessor.java#L49) I think you can use REST API to check the size of only Map and Queue.